# Fullscreen details overlay with beamer location

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-beamer

Disclaimer: I'm a flutter beginner building a web only project!.

I have a screen which contains a set of items.
Once one of those items is tapped, a full screen overlay should be displayed with more details about the item.

Functionally, would be very similar to this screenshot, but obviously with different content in both, the main page and the overlay.

[image]

Let's call this two screens `ItemsWidget` and `ItemDetailsWidget`. The later has a background opacity of 0.5, which means it should be translucent.

As I'm using [beamer](https://pub.dev/packages/beamer/) for navigation.
I have declared the location `/items` for `ItemsWidget` and `/items/:item_id` for `ItemDetailsWidget`

The routing and setup works fine and I can navigate between the widgets.

However, when the `ItemDetailsWidget` is displayed (even with the translucent background), the `ItemsWidget` dissapears from underneath.

In the screenshot example, it would look something like this:

[image]

I understand `ItemDetailsWidget` it's replacing the entire screen content, but I would like to have it on top of `ItemsWidget`.

I guess this could be done with a `Stack` widget and two children widgets, but that would have to be in the same beamer location.
I want to have to different beamer locations for url routing.

Any ideas or tips? is this even possible with beamer?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is to use a beamer dialog route as demonstrated in the following example.

https://github.com/slovnicki/beamer/blob/master/examples/books_dialogroute/lib/main.dart

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Beamer, but why don't you implement that functionality as custom dialog window?

The flutter dismiss anything that is not on the screen to prevent memory leaks and unnecessary use of widgets that are not visible.

in case you will be interested in converting the functionality into dialog, there is nice article about dialogs at:  https://material.io/components/dialogs/flutter

Comment: How would you route directly to the dialog with a URL with browser back button support to go to the list view? I think that's the key problem. I tried putting a dialog on the Beamer location but that also overrides the entire screen.